# correct REST API for autosuggest on google?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I feel silly asking this.. but its doing my head..

if I use 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json' and set the input parameter to say - 'Palazzo Cast' I will get about 5 suggestions - none of which will be the one I'm looking for. if I set input to 'Palazzo Castellania' I will get zero results - even though there is a place called this (see below). I've set the region parameter to 'mt'...

If I use 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext' and set the input parameter to 'Palazzo Castellania' - I will get 'the Ministry of Health' - which is correct - however, if I put a partial string in I'll get only a single candidate which will be something different - there doesn't seem to be a way to get multiple place candidates?

I'm guessing from an API side - I have to do a multi-step process - but it would be good to get some input.

My thoughts:
I start with 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json' - if I get an empty result, I try 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext'

if I get a single result from either then I can pass the placeID to the places API to get more detailed data.

Make sense? It feels argly..

---

Edit
So watching how https://www.google.com.mt/ does it... while typing it uses suggest (and never gives the right answer, just like the API) and then when I hit enter it uses search and gives the correct answer... leading me to the conclusion that there is actually two databases happening!

Answer (score 0):

Basically "its by design".. there is no fix as of Feb 2023.. My thoughts are to cache results and do a first search against that otherwise I'll probably use bing or here